# Vertical Align text in a Label

Tags: html, css

I have been asked to vertically align the text in the labels for the fields in a form but I don't understand why they are not moving. I have tried putting in-line styles using `vertical-align:top;` and other attributes like `bottom` and `middle` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
<dd>
   <label class="<?=$email_confirm_class;?>" 
          style="text-align:right; padding-right:3px">Confirm Email</label>
   <input class="text" type="text" 
          style="border:none;" name="email_confirm" 
          id="email_confirm" size="18" value="<?=$_POST['email_confirm'];?>" 
          tabindex="4" /> 
   *
</dd>
```

Comment: As usual for CSS questions: 10 wrong answers and one general solution (in this case display table, table-cell and vertical-align middle). Why is CSS still the brittle rat's nest that it's always been? Mostly because it's difficult to undo the mountain of poor decision making that went into the original "specifications" (and I use the term loosely).  

This should absolutely be a simple property on the label, as should putting the text on the left versus the right. Why isn't that the case? Horrifically poor implementation decisions.

Comment: @RickO'Shea I completely agree. Maybe it's my background but I come from WPF/Silverlight/WinForms where I'd spend most of my time writing the useful code. With CSS I spend so much time trying to get the layouts of web apps correct and I'm not even trying to develop for multiple device sizes!

Answer (score 83):

You can use flexbox in 2018+:

```
.label-class {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Browser support: https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @RickO'Shea This is the only thing that worked for me. I think it's because my label is in an input-group which is displayed as flex. So even though it might work for your case, it does apply in some other cases.

Comment: This works with the latest version of Bootstrap. Thanks.

Comment: 2023 is still the answer!

Answer (score 43):

Vertical alignment only works with **inline** or **inline-block** elements, and it's only relative to other inline[-block] elements. Because you float the label, it becomes a **block** element.

The simplest solution in your case is to set the label to `display: inline-block` and add `vertical-align: middle` to the labels and the inputs. (You might find that the height of the text is such that vertical align won't make any difference anyway.)

Answer (score 27):

Have you tried `line-height`? It won't solve your problems if there are multiple row labels, but it can be a quick solution.

Comment: Saved alot of time :)

Answer (score 17):

The `vertical-align` style is used in table cells, so that won't do anything for you here.

To align the labels to the input boxes, you can use `line-height`:

```
line-height: 25px;
```

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and solved it wrapping the `label` into a `div` and setting the following styles:

```
<div style="display: table; vertical-align: middle">
  <label style="display: table-cell;" ... > ... </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer hints at a general solution, but it's immediately useful to know more about [`display:table`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#table-values)

Answer (score 5):

This is what I usually do to "vertical align" text inside labels:

```
label {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   padding-top: 2px; /*This needs to be modified to fit */
}
```

It won't scale very nicely, but it works.

Comment: It does not scale indeed. Please don't use this. Any other answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this trying to add labels o some vertical radio boxes. I had to do this:

```
<%: Html.RadioButton("RadioGroup1", "Yes") %><label style="display:inline-block;padding-top:2px;">Yes</label><br />
<%: Html.RadioButton("RadioGroup1", "No") %><label style="display:inline-block;padding-top:3px;">No</label><br />
<%: Html.RadioButton("RadioGroup1", "Maybe") %><label style="display:inline-block;padding-top:4px;">Maybe</label><br />
```

This gets them to display properly, where the label is centered on the radio button, though I had to increment the top padding with each line, as you can see. The code isn't pretty, but the result is.

Answer (score 1):

```css
label {
        padding: 10px 0;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Add some padding-top and padding-bottom instead of height.

Comment: Perhaps spell out how the style attribute should look like? Perhaps OP does not know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use css on your label.

For example:

```
label {line-height:1em; margin:2px 5px 3px 5px; padding:2px 5px 3px 5px;}
```

Notice that the line-height will adjust the height of the line itself, whereas margin will dictate how far out other elements will be outside the lable and padding will dictate any inner space from the outside edge of the label.  The margin and padding work like this (clockwise:  Top Right Bottom Left), so 2px 5px 3px 5px is:

2px Top
5px Right
3px Bottom
5px Left

Answer (score 0):

To do this you should alter the vertical-align property of the input.

```
<dd><label class="<?=$email_confirm_class;?>" style="text-align:right; padding-right:3px">Confirm Email</label><input class="text" type="text" style="vertical-align: middle; border:none;" name="email_confirm" id="email_confirm" size="18" value="<?=$_POST['email_confirm'];?>" tabindex="4" /> *</dd>
```

Here is a more complete version. It has been tested in IE 8 and it works.
see the difference by removing the vertical-align: middle from the input:

```
<html><head></head><body><dl><dt>test</dt><dd><label class="test" style="text-align:right; padding-right:3px">Confirm Email</label><input class="text" type="text" style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 22px" name="email_confirm" id="email_confirm" size="28" value="test" tabindex="4" /> *</dd></dl></body></html>
```

Comment: In my experience text fields are quite hard to tame, and vertical padding works more reliably.

Comment: `vertical-align` doesn't do anything here (IE 8).

Comment: I've tested it in IE8 and FF (ubuntu) removed the vertical-align to see the effect and it is working perfectly. I updated the example as well.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me.  I am using ASP.Net MVC with Bootstrap.
I used the following successfully:

```
.label-middle { 
    padding-top:6px;
}

<label id="lblX" class="label-middle" ></label>
```

This vertically aligned the label with the textbox next to it.

Answer (score 0):

If your label is in table, padding may cause it to expand. To avoid this you may use margin:

```html
div label {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: -0.2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add any padding or edit the line-height!

Instead, just make sure that when you have an HTML like this :

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name=""><span>Checkbox Text</span></label>
```

Just make sure that the input height and width are the same, and the the text has the same font size.

Then, it will look perfectly fine and looks centered.

Comment: I think if you're going to answer like this, you'd be better off providing a link to a working example, and fleshing out the code that you have with the associated styles. It'll be a lot more helpful that way.

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
<label class="styling_target">Label Text</label>
<input />
```

Do this instead:

```
<label>
  <span class="styling_target">Label Text</span>
  <input />
</label>
```

Styling a label doesn't really work, but you can have arbitrary HTML inside it, and you can style that.

Answer (score 0):

Force relative positions to provide top/bottom adjustments

```css
.whatever {
    position: relative;
}

.whatever .input {
    position: relative;
}

.whatever span {
    position: relative;
    top: -2px; /* adjust this up or down */
}
```

```html
<label class="whatever">
    <input type="checkbox"><span>my thing</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the **vertical-align** property of the label to **top**.

```css
label {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
 <label for="desc">Description</label>
 <textarea name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding the `display:flex` property to the label will get the job done!

Answer (score -1):

Lacking in elegance, pure html, no CSS solution:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <label></label>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input></input>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```