# DL Tag - Vertical align text in DT Tag, color background and have same height as DD Tag

Tags: css, list-definition

Given the following html & CSS:

```css
dl.table-display {
  float: left;
  width: 520px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
}

.table-display dt {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.table-display dd {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<dl class="table-display">
  <dt>Key 1</dt>
  <dd>Value 1</dd>
  <dt>Key 2</dt>
  <dd>Value 2<br/>With line breaks<br/>and line breaks</dd>
</dl>
```

I am trying to center the text in the DT & DD tags and have the DT tag background color cover 100% of the longer DD tag. Create a .html file with the above code to see how it looks now. I did have this as a table but I am forced to use the DL markup now. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to put the `dd` inside the `dt` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting a height for your dt elements will 'stretch' the background, and so long as this height is >= the height of the contained dd's, then it will look as you want.

```
dt{height:100px;}
```

providing text-align:center on the dl tag will center your text.

```
dl{text-align:center;}
```

The hard part is then trying to vertically align the text to the middle. An option for this is to contain the text in an absolute positioned div.. but is a bit messy.

```
<dt><div>Key 1</div></dt>

dt{position:relative;height:100px;}
dt div{position:absolute;bottom:50px;}
```

check here for other options/solutions [Vertical Align text in a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554941/vertical-align-text-in-a-label)

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

`dt {display:table-cell}` will let you vertically align the text in the dt. In my case, I needed my text vertically aligned to the bottom. Example:

```
dt {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:5em;
}
```

BTW, `dl {display:table-cell}` will put each `<dl>` in a horizontal line, similar to floating (or similar to a row of table cells). If you set a height to the `<dt>` and add a border to the bottom, that bottom border will form a straight line like a table cell border.