# Vertical align span-Element in label-Element

Tags: html, css

I have a similar problem to this question:
[Vertical Align text in a Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554941/vertical-align-text-in-a-label)

My HTML-Structure looks like this:

```
<label>
    <span>Comment:</span>
    <textarea>Some Default-Text</textarea>
</label>
```

And I'm trying to vertically-align the span-element to the top of the label-Element.

That's my css-Code:

```
label{
    display: block;
}

label span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
}

.createForm textarea{
    width: 67.7%;
    resize: vertical;
}
```

I already tried setting the display of the label-tag to inline-block and adding the vertical-align attribute, but nothing happened.

Anyone knows the reason for this issue?

Comment: You are saying you already tried, but are you really sure you added `vertical-align: top`? It seems to work with just it: http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/XE5Fy/

Comment: @acdcjunior I put the align inside the label-element, which didn't work :(
  No idea why I haven't thought about putting it into the span-element  *ashame*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to span

```
label span{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DWv4G/)

Although I would suggest you to use `div` instead of `label` in such cases. `label` is not meant for having child elements.